# Jquery selectric plugin update options values problems

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectric

i'm using jquery and jquery seletric plugin and it works fine but i need to refill options data after an ajax call.

```
$('#mySelectID').empty();
     $.each(myResultAjaxObject, function(i, item) {
         $('#mySelectID').append($('<option>', {
             value: myValue,
             text: imyTextValue
         }));
     });
$('#mySelectID').selectpicker('refresh');
```

This code run for multiple drop-down list and it fills them correctly, the wrong thing is that mark as selected the first child of each drop-down list.

Probably i'm missing something in the selectpicker update procedure.

Any help would be appreciated.

Davide

Answer (score 0):

try to set some delay and check:

```
setTimeout(() => {
  jQuery('#mySelectID').selectpicker('refresh');
}, 500);
```

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion but unfortunately the problem is still there..